# Substituting stdout before writing to file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am trying to substibute a variable from a stdout stream before writing it to file.

This is a tshark utility that is parsing some DNS stats and outputting to a file, it runs in the background

```
#tshark > $FILE 2>&1 &
```

The output looks something like this:

64.6.64.6       10.13.0.41      domain.com     3

What I am trying to do is substitute column 2 value with the regex output below:

```
grep 10.13.0.41 /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log |awk -F'[,:]' '{print $3}'

190.171.88.59
```

End result is $FILE will contain the line:

64.6.64.6       190.171.88.59      domain.com     3

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show representative contents of `/etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log` as you don't need to add a call to grep for this and the way you're using grep would produce false matches in multiple ways so we need to know what that file looks like in able to be able to help you parse it robustly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` for this job:

```
cat ./filter.sh
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='$\n' read -r line; do
    # Replace "echo 190.171.88.59" below with your commands to get the IP address
    NEW_IP=$(echo 190.171.88.59)
    printf '%s\n' "$line" | sed "s/\ [0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+/\ ${NEW_IP}/"
done

$ cat tmp.txt 
64.6.64.6 10.13.0.41 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 1.1.1.1 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 2.2.2.2 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 3.3.3.3 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 4.4.4.4 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 1.2.3.4 domain.com 3

$ cat tmp.txt | ./filter.sh 
64.6.64.6 190.171.88.59 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 190.171.88.59 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 190.171.88.59 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 190.171.88.59 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 190.171.88.59 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 190.171.88.59 domain.com 3
```

So in the end you'll have something like:

```
tshark | ./filter.sh > $FILE 2>&1 &
```

If the output takes time to show up in `$FILE`, you may have to check if `tshark` is buffering when printing to the pipe (see the `-l` parameter).

Comment: Thank you, I used the pipe logic and it worked.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=$(grep 10.13.0.41 /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log | awk -F'[,:]' '{print $3}')
tshark 2>&1 | awk -v ip="$ip" '{$2 = ip} 1' > "$FILE" &
```

- `ip=$( cmd )` assigns bash variable `ip` to the output of the command.
- Awk option `-v ip="$ip"` sets the awk variable `ip` to the value of
  bash variable `$ip` then the second field is replaced with it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question yet but it sounds like all you need is:

```
tshark |
awk '
NR==FNR {
    map[$1] = $3
    next
}
$2 in map {
    $2 = map[$2]
}
{ print }
' FS='[,:]' /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log FS=' ' -
```

`map[$1] = $3` is just a wild guess that `/etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log` has content like `10.13.0.41,foo,190.171.88.59,bar` that maps one IP address in field 1 to another in field 3. Once you provide an example of the content of that file we can tweak that line of code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

maybe make it a `single through pipeline`, plus one `sub-shell` ?

```
tshark 2>&1 | {m,g}awk '$(_+=_=_~_)=__' __="$( 
     
  {m,g}awk 'BEGIN { _*=(FS  = "^[^,:]*[,:][^,:]*[,:]|[,:].+$" (OFS = ORS = _))
       } _ { exit } _ = NF *= /[^0-9]?0?10[.]0?13[.]0+[.]0?41[^0-9]?/' \
                              \   
                         '/etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log' )" > "$FILE" &

64.6.64.6 190.171.88.59 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 190.171.88.59 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 190.171.88.59 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 190.171.88.59 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 190.171.88.59 domain.com 3
64.6.64.6 190.171.88.59 domain.com 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You already found that `awk` will do the job. You could simply pipe the output of `tshark` into `awk`,

```
(tshark 2>&1 | awk .... >$FILE) &
```